# Constructive Dilemma

Tags: logic

If I start with nothing more than $\left(h\rightarrow p\right)\land\left(s\rightarrow w\right)$, how do I prove $\left(h\vee s\right)\rightarrow\left(p\vee w\right)$? I'm using Copi's rules of inference.

I can see that the proof involves showing that the second premise of a constructive dilemma implies the conclusion of a constructive dilemma when given the first premise of a constructive dilemma. I can also see that the proof is likely (although not certain) to involve a hypothetical syllogism, as the conclusion is in the form of a hypothetical proposition. Damned if I can get anything to work though.

Comment: Isn’t that already one of Copi’s rules of inference?

Comment: Unfortunately not. He gives 9 very basic argument forms, and 10 substitution forms. Somehow some combination of them (using only one at a time) should enable us to arrive at the conclusion stated.

Comment: And are those $19$ rules independent of each other?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They are related insofar as they are (obviously) consistent with each other. The argument forms are (1) modus ponens, (2) modus tollens, (3) hypothetical syllogism, (4) disjunctive syllogism, (5) constructive dilemma, (6) absorption, (7) simplification, (8) conjunction, and (9) addition.

Comment: The substitution forms are (1) De Morgan's theorems, (2) commutation, (3) association, (4) distribution, (5) double negation, (6) transposition, (7) material implication, (8) material equivalence, (9) exportation, and (10) tautology.

Comment: You are trying to prove the constructive dilemma holds, right?

Comment: The argument form of constructive dilemma states (P > Q) & (R >S), (P V R), therefore (Q V S). Note: I am *not* given the second premise, (P V R), but rather supposed to *prove* that this second premise implies the conclusion (given nothing but the first premise).

Comment: Can you state exportation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

1.$\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\land\left(r\rightarrow s\right)$  /  $\therefore\left(p\vee r\right)\rightarrow\left(q\vee s\right)$

2.$\left(p\rightarrow q\right)$ [1,Simp.]

3.$\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\vee s$ [2,Add]

4.$\left(r\rightarrow s\right)\land\left(p\rightarrow q\right)$ [1,Com.]

5.$\left(r\rightarrow s\right)$ [4,Simp.]

6.$\left(r\rightarrow s\right)\vee q$ [5,Add]

7.$\left[\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\vee s\right]\land\left[\left(r\rightarrow s\right)\vee q\right]$ [3,6,Conj.]

8.$\left[\left(\lnot p\vee q\right)\vee s\right]\land\left[\left(\lnot r\vee s\right)\vee q\right]$ [7,Impl.]

9.$\left[\lnot p\vee\left(q\vee s\right)\right]\land\left[\lnot r\vee\left(s\vee q\right)\right]$ [8,Assoc.]

10.$\left[\left(q\vee s\right)\vee\lnot p\right]\land\left[\lnot r\vee\left(q\vee s\right)\right]$ [9,Com.]

11.$\left[\left(q\vee s\right)\vee\lnot p\right]\land\left[\left(q\vee s\right)\vee\lnot r\right]$ [10,Com.]

12.$\left(q\vee s\right)\vee\left(\lnot p\land\lnot r\right)$ [11,Dist.]

13.$\left(\lnot p\land\lnot r\right)\vee\left(q\vee s\right)$ [12,Com.]

14.$\lnot\left(\lnot p\land\lnot r\right)\rightarrow\left(q\vee s\right)$ [13,Impl.]

15.$\left(\lnot\lnot p\vee\lnot\lnot r\right)\rightarrow\left(q\vee s\right)$ [14,De M.]

16.$\left(p\vee r\right)\rightarrow\left(q\vee s\right)$ [14,D.N.]

QED.

Note: I sometimes apply one of Copi's rules twice on one line (for reasons of space), but only if it is the same rule (for example, I apply the rule of implication twice in line 8).

Comment: Nice work!  It's always a pain in the ass when systems don't have conditional proof!

Answer (score 0):

By constructive dilemma,
$$(((h \to p) \wedge (s \to w)) \wedge (h \vee s)) \to (p \vee w).$$
Hence, by exportation,
$$((h \to p) \wedge (s \to w)) \to ((h \vee s) \to (p \vee w)).$$